# How do I change this Contact Form's Javascript so that IF a key is something else, perform different action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Contact Form that utilizes Google Scripts. It successfully sends the email and formats it decently to my inbox, but there are 2 problems:

-I need it so that IF var key is equal to 'Action', then do not display it in the email it sends. Because right now, "**Action** send_message" is getting included in the email and I don't like that.

For this, I have unsuccessfully tried things like:

```
for (var idx in order) { 
    var key = order[idx]; 
    //Skip this entry into the email output if it is the Action 
    if( key === 'Action') {
        continue
    }
```

It seems to not react to this code at all.

-I also need it so that if a city is selected, e.g. Alachua, that the email says 'Alachua' instead of 'Florida_Alachua'. But I can't add a NAME to an option since apparently options don't have that property. I also can't do the quick fix of changing the VALUE of the `<option>` to resolve this step, because of other code I have that conflicts with this route.

Google Scripts Code:

```
/******************************************************************************
     * This tutorial is based on the work of Martin Hawksey twitter.com/mhawksey  *
     * But has been simplified and cleaned up to make it more beginner friendly   *
     * All credit still goes to Martin and any issues/complaints/questions to me. *
     ******************************************************************************/

// if you want to store your email server-side (hidden), uncomment the next line
var TO_ADDRESS = "myemail@email.com";

// spit out all the keys/values from the form in HTML for email
// uses an array of keys if provided or the object to determine field order
function formatMailBody(obj, order) {
  var result = "";
  if (!order) {
    order = Object.keys(obj);
  }

  // loop over all keys in the ordered form data
  for (var idx in order) {
    var key = order[idx];
    result += "<h4 style='text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 0'>" + key + "</h4><div>" + sanitizeInput(obj[key]) + "</div>";
    // for every key, concatenate an `<h4 />`/`<div />` pairing of the key name and its value, 
    // and append it to the `result` string created at the start.
  }
  return result; // once the looping is done, `result` will be one long string to put in the email body
}

// sanitize content from the user - trust no one 
// ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#appendUntrusted(String)
function sanitizeInput(rawInput) {
   var placeholder = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(" ");
   placeholder.appendUntrusted(rawInput);

   return placeholder.getContent();
 }

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    record_data(e);

    // shorter name for form data
    var mailData = e.parameters;

    // names and order of form elements (if set)
    var orderParameter = e.parameters.formDataNameOrder;
    var dataOrder;
    if (orderParameter) {
      dataOrder = JSON.parse(orderParameter);
    }

    // determine recepient of the email
    // if you have your email uncommented above, it uses that `TO_ADDRESS`
    // otherwise, it defaults to the email provided by the form's data attribute
    var sendEmailTo = (typeof TO_ADDRESS !== "undefined") ? TO_ADDRESS : mailData.formGoogleSendEmail;

    // send email if to address is set
    if (sendEmailTo) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: String(sendEmailTo),
        subject: "Contact form submitted",
        // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
        htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData, dataOrder)
      });
    }

    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}


/**
 * record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
 * e is the data received from the POST
 */
function record_data(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000); // hold off up to 30 sec to avoid concurrent writing

  try {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // log the POST data in case we need to debug it

    // select the 'responses' sheet by default
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetName = e.parameters.formGoogleSheetName || "responses";
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    var oldHeader = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var newHeader = oldHeader.slice();
    var fieldsFromForm = getDataColumns(e.parameters);
    var row = [new Date()]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp

    // loop through the header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < oldHeader.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
      var field = oldHeader[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);

      // mark as stored by removing from form fields
      var formIndex = fieldsFromForm.indexOf(field);
      if (formIndex > -1) {
        fieldsFromForm.splice(formIndex, 1);
      }
    }

    // set any new fields in our form
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldsFromForm.length; i++) {
      var field = fieldsFromForm[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);
      newHeader.push(field);
    }

    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; // get next row
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    // update header row with any new data
    if (newHeader.length > oldHeader.length) {
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, newHeader.length).setValues([newHeader]);
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(error);
  }
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
    return;
  }

}

function getDataColumns(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).filter(function(column) {
    return !(column === 'formDataNameOrder' || column === 'formGoogleSheetName' || column === 'formGoogleSendEmail' || column === 'honeypot');
  });
}

function getFieldFromData(field, data) {
  var values = data[field] || '';
  var output = values.join ? values.join(', ') : values;
  return output;
}
```

Contact Form HTML

```
<section id="contact-form">
    <form id="gform"
        class="contact-form" method="post" 
        action="(Google Scripts URL)"
        enctype="text/plain">

        <p>
            <label for="name">Your Name <font face="Arial" color="red">*</font></label>
            <input type="text" style="height:35px;" class="heighttext required" name="name" id="name" class="required" title="* Please provide your name">
        </p>

        <p>

            <label>Your Location <font face="Arial" color="red">*</font></label>

            <select name="Location" id="column_select" style="height:35px;" class="required" title=" * Please provide your location">
                <option selected value="col00">-- State --</option>       
                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                <option value="California">California</option>
                <option value="Florida">Florida</option>  
            </select>

            <select name="City" id="layout_select" style="height:35px;">     
                <option disabled selected value="Florida">-- City --</option> 
                <option name="Alachua" value="Florida_Alachua">Alachua</option>   
                <option name="Alford" value="Florida_Alford">Alford</option>     
            </select>

         </p>           


         <p>
             <input type="submit" value="Send Message" id="submit" class="pp-btn special">
             <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" id="contact-loader" alt="Loading...">
             <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_message">                                           
         </p>
    </form>

</section><!-- #contact-form -->
```

Form Handler Javascript

```
(function() {
  function validEmail(email) { // see:
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
  }

  function validateHuman(honeypot) {
    if (honeypot) {  //if hidden form filled up
      console.log("Robot Detected!");
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("Welcome Human!");
    }
  }

  // get all data in form and return object
  function getFormData() {
    var form = document.getElementById("gform");
    var elements = form.elements;

    var fields = Object.keys(elements).filter(function(k) {
          return (elements[k].name !== "honeypot");
    }).map(function(k) {

      if(elements[k].name !== undefined) {
        return elements[k].name;
      // special case for Edge's html collection
      }else if(elements[k].length > 0){
        return elements[k].item(0).name;
      }

    }).filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) == pos && item;
    });

    var formData = {};
    fields.forEach(function(name){
      var element = elements[name];

      // singular form elements just have one value

      formData[name] = element.value;                     

      // when our element has multiple items, get their values         

      if (element.length) {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
          var item = element.item(i);
          if (item.checked || item.selected) {
            data.push(item.value);
          }
        }
        formData[name] = data.join(', ');
      } 


    });

    // add form-specific values into the data
    formData.formDataNameOrder = JSON.stringify(fields);
    formData.formGoogleSheetName = form.dataset.sheet || "responses"; // default sheet name
    formData.formGoogleSendEmail = form.dataset.email || ""; // no email by default

    console.log(formData);
    return formData;
  }

  function handleFormSubmit(event) {  // handles form submit without any jquery
    event.preventDefault();           // we are submitting via xhr below
    var data = getFormData();         // get the values submitted in the form

    /* OPTION: Remove this comment to enable SPAM prevention, see README.md
    if (validateHuman(data.honeypot)) {  //if form is filled, form will not be submitted
      return false;
    }
    */

    if( data.email && !validEmail(data.email) ) {   // if email is not valid show error
      var invalidEmail = document.getElementById("email-invalid");
      if (invalidEmail) {
        invalidEmail.style.display = "block";
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      disableAllButtons(event.target);
      var url = event.target.action;  //
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', url);
      // xhr.withCredentials = true;
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          console.log( xhr.status, xhr.statusText )
          console.log(xhr.responseText);


          //document.getElementById("gform").style.display = "none"; // hide form

          /*
          var thankYouMessage = document.getElementById("thankyou_message");
          if (thankYouMessage) {
            thankYouMessage.style.display = "block";
          }
          */



          return;
      };
      // url encode form data for sending as post data
      var encoded = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) {
          return encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[k])
      }).join('&')
      xhr.send(encoded);
    }
  }
  function loaded() {
    console.log("Contact form submission handler loaded successfully.");
    // bind to the submit event of our form
    var form = document.getElementById("gform");
    form.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit, false);
  };
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false);

  function disableAllButtons(form) {
    var buttons = form.querySelectorAll("button");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
})();
```

finally, this is the extra code that would break if I simply tried changing the value of option to, e.g., 'Alachua' instead of 'Flordia_Alachua'. https://jsfiddle.net/hmatt843/504dgmqy/19/

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try `console.log(key)` before `if( key === 'Action')`.  I think you'll find that `key` never equals `'Action'`, exactly. Looks like you'll need  `if( key === 'action')`, instead.
2. If you wish to remove part of string value, try the `replace` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

It also looks like you're trying to work with `elements[k].name` when you mean to be working with `elements[k].value`.

I believe your code should look something like...

```
function(k) {
    if(elements[k].value !== undefined) {
        return elements[k].value.replace('Florida_', '');
     // special case for Edge's html collection
    } else if(elements[k].length > 0){
        return elements[k].item(0).value.replace('Florida_', '');
    }
}
```

... or something to that effect.

In the future, you may want to make it easier for folks trying to help you by posting only the portions of code your having trouble with, and breaking your questions into different posts.  A lot to sift through up there.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks! Changing it to 'action' did indeed work. But the second part does not for some reason. Could it be because 'Florida_Alachua' is a value  and maybe name.replace code doesn't interact with values? I don't know, I tried things like `return elements[k].item(0).value.replace('Florida_', '');` (after trying your code, of course) and it seemed to not even change anything. Further advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `console.log` is your best friend.  Instead of `return`ing the value right away, capture it in a variable, `console.log(value)`, the `return value`.

But in this case, I'm seeing the issue, and will update my answer.

Comment: I assume it is the solution, but after an hour of trying different code, I can't get this to work. Do you think there's a way to do it from the Google Script side instead, i.e. `if( key === 'City') {  something like that replace code  }` ?

Comment: @matthew - email me at john dot mealy at gmail dot com, if you're still having troubles.  We could set up a screenshare to poke around.

Answer (score 1):

The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

```
Var splitValue = elements[k].item(0).value.split("");
splitValue[1] will give you a string of characters after the delimeter () in this case.
```